# Basic C++ String Pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Why it is not throwing a error in line 2?

```
char *p = "Hello";
p = "Bye";
```

`*p` is the variable so `p` is the address of the variable `*p`.
Please someone explain me what is the case in above code?

Comment: "`p` is the address of the variable `p`" -- You may want to take a second look at this sentence ;)

Comment: Please be more specific about the behaviour you expect in constrast to the actual behaviour.

Comment: Maybe it will help if I tell you that `char *p = "Hello";` is exactly the same as `char* p = "Hello";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*p` is not "the variable".  `p` is the variable and it is a pointer.  C and C++ have the odd looking declaration syntax in which you declare a variable with the same kind of syntax used to access the variable.

```
char *p;
```

In that declaration we are declaring `p`, not `*p` but declaring `p` to be the thing `p` would need to be for `*p` to be a `char`

```
char *p = "Hello";
```

Now it may be even another step less intuitive, because the thing on the right of the `=` is the initial value for `p` not the initial value for `*p`.  That is how C and C++ work and is easy to get used to and understand, even if the meanings of the left and right side of that initially seem counter-intuitive.

So your example:

```
char *p = "Hello";
p = "Bye";
```

I can see why someone who doesn't know C or C++ might think there is a different level of indirection to the use of `p` on the first line vs. the second.  But actually on both lines `p` is a pointer and the address of a text literal is being stored in that pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not *C++ String Pointers*, those are C-Strings. It is not throwing a error because a string-literal is itself a pointer to the first element. `p` is the pointer, `*p` is the first element of you *String*

Comment: It's not a game-changer here, but string literals are arrays, not pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example

```
  int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
  int * p1, * p2;

  p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 = address of firstvalue
  p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue
  *p1 = 10;          // value pointed to by p1 = 10
  *p2 = *p1;         // value pointed to by p2 = value pointed to by p1
  p1 = p2;           // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied)
  *p1 = 20;          // value pointed to by p1 = 20

  cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << '\n';
  cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The problem you have is p is the variable with its pointer.

Answer (score -2):

In the first case, p is assigned the address of the string. In the second case, p is reassigned the address of another string 
EDIT - String literals are not allocated in the stack. Thanks to Q

Comment: String literals are not allocated on the stack : they have static lifetime.

Comment: Rather than have wrong statement and an edit saying they are wrong, why not remove the wrong statements altogether!?